# Executing mount command from java / Child Shell cannot access the mounted directories

Tags: java, shell, centos, mount

I have a python script that needs to be executed from java code . I use the below command :

```
 ScriptResult result = executor.executeCommand(Script,
            params.getParams(), false);
```

But executor.executeCommand() forks a new shell . I had run a mount command earlier and the contents of /mnt/folder1 are accessible from parent shell but not accessible from the newly forked child shell .

I have tried to execute the mount command , just  before the executor.executeCommand() step using the following :

```
     String cmd = new String("/bin/mount ip:/folder1 /mnt/folder1");
     Process p = new ProcessBuilder(cmd).start();
```

and also

```
    String cmd = new String("mount"); String[] arg = new
    String[]{" ip:/folder1 ,"/mnt/folder1"}; Process pr =
 Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```

Both these give the following error :

```
    java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "mount ip:/folder1 /mnt/folder1":
    error=2, No such file or directory                      
   at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1041)                      
   at Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
```

I have made a **myscript.sh** and copied the mount command and the python script command into the myscript . I invoked the myscript throgh java code and it was successful . But I should invoke the mount command from java code and not through a seperate script . Is there any way that I missed out. Thanks in advance .

Comment: Please be careful when copying code and errors. Your second example doesn't compile, and the error messages you get might look similar, but they contain small differences that are very important. In this case, one can tell that this exact error would only be the result of the first attempt and not the second.

Answer (score 1):

try changing

```
 String cmd = new String("/bin/mount ip:/folder1 /mnt/folder1");

 Process p = new ProcessBuilder(cmd).start();
```

to

```
String[] cmd = new String[]{"/bin/mount", "ip:/folder1", "/mnt/folder1"};

Process p = new ProcessBuilder(cmd).start();
```

Comment: Thanks but i did that. still getting the same error.

Comment: @user3559849 the formatting was a little off. Can you double check that you tried the latter here?